# Program using inheritance and need help validating the registrations of the cars being entered

Tags: c++, class, validation, inheritance

This is the program I have created but it has an error in the main file in line 124 but I don't know how to fix it and make it run properly.  If you choose to add a new car, the program will ask you to enter the type, brand, color, year, and registration.  I need to validate the registration and check that it's not repeated.  I have tried that but currently have an error in main (line 124)

**main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"
#include "Automobile.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int Choice, Option;
    string Color, Registration, Brand, Type;
    int Year;
    Car carro[100];
    int Acount = 0;

    do
    {

        cout << "  -----MENU:-----  " << endl;
        cout << "  Select an option from the menu:  " << endl;
        cout << " 1) Enter a New Car  " << endl;
        cout << " 2) View all Cars  " << endl;
        cout << " 3) Exit  " << endl;
        cout << " Enter your choice: ";

        cin >> Choice;

        switch (Choice)
        {

        case 1:

            carro[Acount];

            cout << " What type of car is it: " << endl;
            cout << " 1) Sedan " << endl;
            cout << " 2) Hatchback " << endl;
            cout << " 3) Minivan " << endl;
            cout << " 4) Crossover " << endl;
            cout << " 5) SUV " << endl;
            cout << " 6) Coupe " << endl;
            cout << " 7) Convertible " << endl;
            cout << " 8) Sport " << endl;
            cout << " 9) MPV (Multi Purpose Vehicle) " << endl;
            cout << " 10) Station Wagon " << endl;
            cout << " 11) Truck " << endl;

            cin >> Option;

            switch (Option)
            {

            case 1:
                Type = " Sedan ";
                break;

            case 2:
                Type = " Hatchback ";
                break;

            case 3:
                Type = " Minivan ";
                break;

            case 4:
                Type = " Crossover ";
                break;

            case 5:
                Type = " SUV ";
                break;

            case 6:
                Type = " Coupe ";
                break;

            case 7:
                Type = " Convertible ";
                break;

            case 8:
                Type = " Sport ";
                break;

            case 9:
                Type = " MPV (Multi Purpose Vehicle) ";
                break;

            case 10:
                Type = " Station Wagon ";
                break;

            case 11:
                Type = " Truck ";
                break;

            default:
                cout << " Invalid Choice " << endl;
                break;

            }

            cout << " What color is the car? ";
            cin >> Color;

            cout << " What is the car's brand? ";
            cin >> Brand;

            do 
            {

                cout << " From what year is the car from? ";
                cin >> Year;

            } while (Year <= 1700 || Year >= 2022);

            cout << " What is the car's license plate number? ";
            cin >> Registration;

            carro[Acount].setType(Type);
            carro[Acount].setColor(Color);
            carro[Acount].setBrand(Brand);
            carro[Acount].setYear(Year);
            carro[Acount].setRegistration(Registration);
            Acount++;

            break;

        case 2:

            cout << " ----All Cars Entered---- " << endl;
            cout << "______________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < Acount; i++)
            {

                cout << " The car is a: " << carro[i].getType() << endl;
                cout << " The car is: " << carro[i].getColor() << endl;
                cout << " The car's brand is: " << carro[i].getBrand() << endl;
                cout << " The car is from: " << carro[i].getYear() << endl;
                cout << " The car's license plate is: " << carro[i].getRegistration() << endl;
                cout << "______________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

            }

            break;

        case 3:

            cout << " ----Leaving Program---- " << endl;

            break;

        default:

            cout << " Invalid Input " << endl;

            break;

        }

    } while (Choice != 3);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

**Automobile.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Automobile
{

private:

    string Color;
    int Year;
    string Type;

public:

    Automobile();
    ~Automobile();
    string getColor();
    int getYear();
    string getType();
    void setColor(string);
    void setYear(int);
    void setType(string);

};
```

**Car.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Automobile.h"

using namespace std;

class Car : public Automobile
{

private:

    string Registration;
    string Brand;

public:

    Car();
    ~Car();
    string getRegistration();
    string getBrand();
    void setRegistration(const Car[], int, string);
    void setBrand(string);

};
```

**Automobile.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Automobile.h"

using namespace std;

Automobile::Automobile()
{

    Color = "";
    Year = 0;
    Type = "";

}

Automobile::~Automobile()
{



}

string Automobile::getColor()
{

    return Color;

}

int Automobile::getYear()
{

    if (Year >= 1700 && Year <= 2022)
    {

        return Year;

    }

    else
    {

        cout << " Invalid Year " << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

}

string Automobile::getType()
{

    return Type;

}

void Automobile::setColor(string color)
{

    Color = color;

}

void Automobile::setYear(int year)
{

    Year = year;

}

void Automobile::setType(string type)
{

    Type = type;

}
```

**Car.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Automobile.h"
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

Car::Car()
{

    Registration = "";
    Brand = "";

}

Car::~Car()
{



}

string Car::getRegistration()
{

    return Registration;

}

string Car::getBrand()
{

    return Brand;

}

void Car::setRegistration(const Car C[], int size, string registration) 
{

    bool end = false;

    while (end == false)
    {

        bool found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {

            if (C[i].Registration.compare(registration) == 0)
                found = true;

        }

        if (found == false)
        {

            end = true;

        }

        else
        {

            cout << " LICENSE NUMBER ALREADY IN USE BY ANOTHER CAR, PLEASE ENTER ANOTHER NUMBER: ";
            cin >> registration;

        }

    }

    Registration = registration;

}

void Car::setBrand(string brand)
{

    Brand = brand;

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend editing your question and adding the error message verbatim. Cut and paste the text. This helps answerers focus in on exactly what you are having trouble with and assists future askers looking for help with a similar problem.

Comment: Also, which line is 124?

Comment: Please see [mre]. It is highly unlikely that you need all of that code -- especially the I/O -- to reproduce a compiler error.

Comment: Dropping the code into a text file (Woo! Almost 400 lines! Read up on creating [mcve]s), rearranging it, and compiling it finds one error: `setRegistration` is called with one argument when it requires 3. Supply the other two and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your:

```
void setRegistration(const Car[], int, string);
```

On line 124 you are calling it with an argument, Registration, which is a string.

```
carro[Acount].setRegistration(Registration);
```

That would cause an error.